# Сокращение строки в выводе

Tags: c++, строки

Пытаюсь изменить символ в строке на `\0`, чтобы выводить её не полностью (т.к. `cout` выводит до нулевого символа), однако программа крашится с  `SIGSEGV`. Почему?

```
int main() {
    char* s = const_cast<char*>("Hello");
    s[4] = '\0';
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь изменить константный массив символов.

Comment: @LLENN да, поэтому и сделал `const_cast`

Comment: `const_cast` не делает буфер, на который указывает `s`, доступным для записи. А чтобы вывести 4 байта достаточно сделать `std::cout.write("Hello", 4);`

Comment: Это не даст вам права писать в константный массив. Вам необходимо выделить нормальный массив, не константный.

Comment: Потому что попытка записи в `const` объект является неопределенным поведением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
char* s = const_cast<char*>("Hello");
```

напишите

```
char s[] = "Hello";
```

и все получится.

Comment: а почему программа крашится то?

Comment: @иван - вы пытаетесь изменить константную область памяти. В том коде, что я написал, `s` - обычный массив, инициализированный константной строкой, и его можно модифицировать.